# Cross platform file modification tracking

Tags: file, filesystems, cross-platform

I'd like to be able to track file modifications to a set of files in a platform-agnostic way.
I don't need any particular information, just the file's full path will do.

I'd prefer to avoid:

- Looping constantly over the files.  That's just horrible!
- Writing platform-specific code.  Especially for Windows or Mac OS X,
  since I have no access to machines running any of those.

---

Disclaimer: I've noticed similar questions on SO, but since most are over 4 years old, I feel this may have changed a lot since then, and they may be outdated.

Comment: how quickly do you need to track the mods? every X minutes, realtime?

Comment: I'd prefer realtime, otherwise, in under a few minutes.